# (Redmine) how to fix an error with custom fields?

Tags: ruby, redmine, custom-fields, redmine-plugins

I have an error, when I'm trying to access to the custom fields page in the administration tab (Administration -> Custom Fields -> 500 error):

```
Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.
```

In the production.log I have the following error:

```
Started GET "/custom_fields" for ip at 2015-02-05 09:33:42 +0000
Processing by CustomFieldsController#index as HTML
  Current user: user (id=1)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8.0ms

ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'Impasse::ExecutionCustomField'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite CustomField.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.):
  app/controllers/custom_fields_controller.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/custom_fields_controller.rb:27:in `index'
```

I also have several plugins installed:

Redmine Agile plugin (Light version)
Scrum and Agile project management plugin for redmine
http://redminecrm.com
RedmineCRM  1.3.5   Configure

Redmine Checklists plugin (Light version)
This is a issue checklist plugin for Redmine
http://redminecrm.com
RedmineCRM  3.0.2   Configure

Redmine Tags
Redmine issues and wiki pages tagging support
https://github.com/redminecrm/redmine_tags/
Aleksey V Zapparov AKA "ixti"   2.0.1-dev   Configure

Redmine Tweaks
Wiki and content extensions
http://github.com/alexandermeindl/redmine_tweaks
AlphaNodes GmbH 0.4.9   Configure

Redmine Wiki Extensions plugin
This is a Wiki Extensions plugin for Redmine
http://www.r-labs.org/projects/r-labs/wiki/Wiki_Extensions_en
Haruyuki Iida   0.6.4

Redmine Work Time plugin
A plugin to view and update TimeEntry by each user
http://www.r-labs.org/projects/worktime

And I checked all these plugins on the clean redmine installation and thay works correctly, without any conflicts. 
Redmine version - 2.6.0

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just an idea: have you had [impasse](https://github.com/kawasima/redmine_impasse) plugin? You can see [`class ExecutionCustomField`](https://github.com/kawasima/redmine_impasse/blob/e6acef61b1be021985c7634c79266313585c1616/app/models/impasse/execution_custom_field.rb#L2) in this plugin. Possible workflow: 1. You installed the plugin 2. Add some custom fields based on this plugin 3. Uninstall plugin (but custom fields are left in your system/DB)

Comment: Hmm, I will check that, thanks

Comment: You was right, I repeated this situation on my clean installation. Do you have any ideas how to solve this? Installing this plugin back fails on migration with:
{
/home/redmine/redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:127:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate
}

Comment: if it fails on migrations it seems to me that it was not uninstalled correctly. The easiest way is comment that migrations that causes the exception. I mean: 1) run migration (maybe with options --trace) 2) find a migration which is wrong 3) comment section `up` and run again 4) when all migration will be passed - uncomment code

Comment: another way might be find and remove invalid records in DB. I mean custom fields are saved in DB and plugin `impasse` added on values to DB. Now Redmine can not extract this value because Redmine can't find required class. If you need not (I think so because the plugin was removed) this custom fields you can just remove this/these record(s)

Comment: It helps, thank you again - you can write an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion we found out that plugin [`impasse`](https://github.com/kawasima/redmine_impasse) left custom fields in DB. After the plugin was removed Redmine can not load these custom fields any more.

Solution: find incorrect records (custom fields are records!) in Db and destroy them manually.